# can't deploy ear file on Weblogic 12c

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

i have EAR file contains jar and war packages.this ear file deploy on glassfish correctly but when deploy this ear file on weblogic 12c, get this error :

> Unable to access the selected application.
>    Error Exception in AppMerge flows' progression
>    Error Exception in AppMerge flows' progression
>   Error Unable to resolve deadlock in factory claims
>   Error Unable to resolve deadlock in factory claims

i check application.xml and name of jar and war packages are correct.anybody have idea for solving this issue ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I too had this problem and tried everything (schemas, project structure, dependant libs, etc). Finally compared my domain with the sample "medrec", the only difference was that I had added SIP support. After removing this support, I can now deploy my EAR with included WAR and EJBs. I assume this is a bug in 12c...

Comment: yeah ! i create new domain without SIP support and everything be fine :).also i think this weblogic 12c bug.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem and I had to create another domain to resolve the issue.The key here is not to use the eclipse tool to create the the domain as the option to create "Basic Weblogic Domain" is not presented.

The option to create a basic weblogic domain is presented when you launch the weblogic domain creation wizard.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the exact same problem today. This problem is associated with the way the Domain was created. If you have used "*Basic WebLogic SIP Server Domain*" then it would occur while installing an ear. You can double check if the Domain is created with Basic SIP or not, go to your `Weblogic Server Domain >> bin >> setDomainEnv (cmd or sh)` file and check if you have the below properties defined.

```
-- set WLSS_HOME=C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_12.1\sip
-- set SIP_ENABLED=true
```

I tried to create the Domain again with JAX-RPC extension instead of Basic SIP and got this problem resolved.